# d3js call some object's method, not global function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, call

The following code fails.
   It only creates brush if `brush` is a global function.

How should i call obj.editor?

```
oneObject.prototype.editor = function(){
  var brush = d3.svg.brush()
   .x(x)
   .extent([new Date(2013, 2, 2, 8), new Date(2013, 2, 2, 18)])
   .on("brushstart", brushed);
  return brush; 
}

var obj = new oneObject();  

var gBrush = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "brush")
.call( function(){return obj.editor(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `call` should take a `selection` as an argument. In your case, you are completely disregarding the passed arguments. A `brush`, on the other hand, is already such function.

The following should work:

```js
var gBrush = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(obj.editor());
```

This is a short form either of the following:

```js
var gBrush = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call( function(selection){ obj.editor()(selection); });
```

Or:

```js
var gBrush = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call( function(selection){ selection.call(obj.editor()); });
```